# How to change the style of Mpart tab in RCP application by css?

Tags: css, swt, styling, e4

I have an application where I want to set the color of a tab dependent on the displayed data, using an id or a tag. 
I could only find examples on how to set the color of selected and unselected tabs. Is there another built in possibility for styling tabs, or will I need an own renderer?

Note:My partstack has so many mpart and for each mpart tab i want to set color depending on data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way to do this with the standard CSS support.

You will have to use the e4 CSS `swt-tab-renderer` property to define a new tab renderer, probably based on the e4 `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering` renderer. Even then I think this will be difficult.

You also use the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.propertyHandler` extension point to define new CSS properties.

The `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.elementProvider` extension point allows you to define new CSS pseudo classes (such as `:active`) but this might be difficult to use in this case because an element provider is already defined.